# Is there any graph database good for both updating graph and data mining?

Tags: graph-databases

I am new to graph database and try to find the right one for us but I haven't. We need something good for both updating graph and data mining.

For graph database like Neo4j we could perform queries and updates really fast. And it will perform very fast when dealing with highly connected data. But it seems not very useful to perform computations on the whole graph. That is what we need for data mining(to run pagerank for example). And GraphLab, Giraph, GraphX, Faunus etc are of this kind. But many of them are not good at like even removing and updating the graph. For example deleting vertices and edges cannot be done explicitly in GraphLab.

Is there anything good for both updating graph and pageranking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Titan](http://titan.thinkaurelius.com) is built with both OLTP and OLAP processing in mind.  It is therefore good at both high-speed read/writes at large scales:

http://thinkaurelius.com/2013/05/13/educating-the-planet-with-pearson/
http://thinkaurelius.com/2013/11/24/boutique-graph-data-with-titan/

You mentioned Faunus as something you looked at for graph analytics.  Faunus is highly tuned to work with Titan.  In fact, as of the most recent release of [Titan at 0.5.0](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/29O1wZY6Bxs), Faunus has been repackaged and distributed directly with Titan as titan-hadoop for even greater integration and support.

Looking forward to Titan 1.0 due in coming months, Titan will look to support [TinkerPop3](https://github.com/tinkerpop/tinkerpop3), which does for OLAP what original versions did for OLTP, in that it generalizes graph analytics frameworks (it already integrates Giraph as the reference implementation).

Since you are in the exploring stage and familiar with Neo4j, I think looking at [TinkerPop3 documentation](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/current) would be a good start as it uses Neo4j for its reference implementation.  [Numerous vendors](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/current/#_graph_vendors) are preparing to support this latest version of TinkerPop and thus developing your application against TinkerPop, lets you get started without having to be tied to a particular graph database in this early stage.  You can save that decision for later once you have more time to evaluate the different implementations available.

If you need to get to work with something right away, then start with Titan 0.5 and consider your migration path to 1.0 when it becomes available.